# How to insert direct current symbol in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hello does anyone know how to insert the direct current symbol ( ⎓  )in Adobe Illustrator please? I copy and paste the character into a text frame but it becomes a cross square which cannot be displayed correctly. I switched to a number of different font types but no luck. I also tried to insert a symbol from Adobe Illustrator but cannot find any. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds like your font does not support that character? That said, this question is more suited for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use the font: Cambria Math and then on your computer keyboard press and hold alt key then the numbers 9107

[insert direct current symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96hWm.jpg)